# Uniform initialization occurs implicitly, even though the int cast operator is declared with the explicit keyword. What is the reason?

Tags: c++, initialization, explicit

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    mutable int val{};
public:
    static constexpr int MAX{ 5 };
public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(int i) : val{ i } {}
    ~Test() { cout << "~Test()" << endl; }

    explicit operator int() const { return val; }   // int()변환 연산자 오버로딩 (반환형식을 기재하지 않는다.)

    void print() const
    {
        ++val;  // mutable 형식이기 때문에 수정가능
        cout << val << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t{ 10 };
    int i = static_cast<int>(t);    // int()변환 연산자가 explicit이라 명시적으로 타입캐스팅을 해주어야한다.
    int j{ t };                     // 근데 얘는 왜 될까..??
}
```

"Uniform initialization occurs implicitly, even though the int cast operator is declared with the explicit keyword. What is the reason?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`int j{ t };` performs [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), which does consider `explicit` conversion function.

> Direct-initialization is more permissive than copy-initialization: copy-initialization only considers non-explicit constructors and non-explicit user-defined conversion functions, while direct-initialization considers all constructors and all user-defined conversion functions.

On the ohter hands, [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) only considers non-explicit conversion functions. Then `int j = t;` is ill-formed.

From the standard, [[class.conv.fct]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.fct#2)

> A conversion function may be explicit ([[dcl.fct.spec]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.spec)), in which case
>   it is only considered as a user-defined conversion for
>   direct-initialization ([[dcl.init]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init)). Otherwise, user-defined
>   conversions are not restricted to use in assignments and
>   initializations. [ Example:
>
> ```
> class Y { };
> struct Z {
>   explicit operator Y() const;
> };
>
> void h(Z z) {
>   Y y1(z);          // OK: direct-initialization
>   Y y2 = z;         // ill-formed: copy-initialization
>   Y y3 = (Y)z;      // OK: cast notation
> }
>
> void g(X a, X b) {
>   int i = (a) ? 1+a : 0;
>   int j = (a&&b) ? a+b : i;
>   if (a) {
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Comment: There is no explicit casting declaration in direct initialization, which part is explicit?

Comment: @김정연 Yes, you can think *direct initialization* as a kind of [explicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).